# Minikube - how do I get the ip address/host of backend for front end web app?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, minikube

Using kubernetes and minikube, let's say you have:

> deployment A
>
> Web app with loadBalancer type service

> deployment B
>
> express.js back end for apis with loadBalancer type service.

To do fetch calls in deployment A, how do I know what the host or ipaddress is for deployment B?

- Without using NGINX reverse proxy for the api on deployment A.
- Without having to bring up deployment A first, getting ip address
  from `kubectl get service` and hard coding it in the front end app of
  deployment A. I would be ok with this if the ip address never changed but it does.

Comment: do you just need to call apis from deployment A in deployment B? then you do not need the ip address in your application. instead of calling $deployment-b-ip you call $deployment-b-service-name. also, if your deployment B just serves requests to deployment b, a service of type ClusterIP would be the more appropriate choice

Comment: do you mean the dns name space `deployment-b-service-name.default`? that will only resolve in the cluster and not in the browser.

Comment: Hello @dman. Could you share your current yaml configs?